# where can I find OWL file?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I am doing a project on irrigation systems, for that I am searching for owl files for water sprinklers. Can some help me where I can find OWL files, not only for this but also for many other classes.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Do not worry of the downvotes! There are some problems on the way you formulated your question which means you lack the basic information on Ontologies and someone found it easier to downvote than to provide an answer.

OWL is a language to model an Ontology and together with RDF are the foundations of Semantic Web (you might want to read about RDF and OWL or maybe have a look at this presentation which can be helpful http://de.slideshare.net/rlovinger/rdf-and-owl).

If you need an ontology to model some problem related to water sprinklers or whatever, you can first search if one exists. Swoogle  (http://swoogle.umbc.edu/) might be a choice or search engine search by using the +keywordyou +ontology (or filetype:owl can be added in google search to limit your search only to files ending in .owl).

Sindice mentioned by another post is a search engine where you can find instances marked or related to "sprinklers"

Comment: I've been very disappointed with swoogle - but it may depend on what kinds of things you're looking for.  I was looking for ontologies related to demographic statistics - [data cube](http://www.w3.org/TR/vocab-data-cube/) examples, etc.

Comment: One more thing: Turtle syntax is used for Owl more than Owl syntax, in my experience.  So search for filetype:ttl, too!

Comment: The question is getting downvotes (and close votes) because it's off topic for Stack Overflow: "Questions asking us to **recommend or find** a tool, library or favorite **off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor actually downgrading a question or an answer for the matter, without any comment on why someone does so is quite unpolite and definitely not helping toward the problem you are pointing.

Comment: The tooltip on the downvote button says quite plainly "This question does not show any research effort."  The question includes no mention of what results have already been found, what sources have already been checked, etc.  It also says "it is unclear or not useful."  If someone downvotes without leaving a comment, it's usually a safe bet that there's an implicit comment along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to learn to find ontologies too.

Consider using [Sindice](http://sindice.com/search?q=sprinkler&nq=&fq=class%3Aowl%3AClass%20predicate%3Ardf%3Atype&interface=advanced), for starters.  However, I'm still trying to learn how to productively narrow search results down to ontologies about what I'm interested in.

Also, consider asking this on [SemanticWeb](http://answers.semanticweb.com/).

Finally, I'd suggest being a little more explicit in the text what you hint at in the title - that you're probably asking someone to "teach you to fish" for ontologies, and just happen to need one for sprinklers.  This will get more answers and fewer downvotes and close-votes, I think/hope.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted, but the Sindice search will provide more instance results than the modelling ontology per se.

Comment: @Al-Punk Right - so you have to use filters to narrow the return, like searching for owl:Ontology in addition to "sprinklers" e.g.

Comment: @EdStaub The question is off-topic here: "Questions asking us to **recommend or find** a tool, library or favorite **off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Answering these kinds of questions encourages people to continue asking them.   In this realm, answers.semanticweb.com would be a better fit, but the question is probably still too broad.